# css inner shadow before image

Tags: css

How to make the image with inner shadow ? When I put the image , the inner shadow has been blocked. Any idea how to make the inner shadow show before image

```css
.img_container{
 height:150px;
 width:200px;
 cursor:pointer;
 background:#fff;
 position:relative;
 -moz-box-shadow:    inset 0 0 10px #000000;
 -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #000000;
 box-shadow:         inset 0 0 10px #000000; 
 
}

.img_container img{
 position:absolute;
 height:150px;
 width:200px;
 
}
```

```html
<div class="img_container">
  <div class="boximgobj">
    <img src="http://minionslovebananas.com/images/gallery/preview/Chiquita-DM2-gallery_minion_cupcake.jpg?w=373&h=400" />
  </div>
</div> 
<div class="img_container">
  <div class="boximgobj">
    <img src="" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if there's better solution but it can achived with `z-index` and `background: transparent`

```css
.img_container{
 height:150px;
 width:200px;
 cursor:pointer;
 background:#fff;
 position:relative;
 -moz-box-shadow:    inset 0 0 10px #000000;
 -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #000000;
 box-shadow:         inset 0 0 10px #000000; 
 background: transparent;
}

.img_container img{
 position:absolute;
 height:150px;
 width:200px;
 z-index:-1;
}
```

```html
<div class="img_container">
  <div class="boximgobj">
    <img src="http://minionslovebananas.com/images/gallery/preview/Chiquita-DM2-gallery_minion_cupcake.jpg?w=373&h=400" />
  </div>
</div> 
<div class="img_container">
  <div class="boximgobj">
    <img src="" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add padding. Problem is the image is over the shadow.

```css
.img_container{
 height:170px;
 width:220px;
 cursor:pointer;
 background:#fff;
 position:relative;
 -moz-box-shadow:    inset 0 0 10px #000000;
 -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #000000;
 box-shadow:         inset 0 0 10px #000000; 
 
}

.img_container img{
 position:absolute;
 height:150px;
 width:200px;
 padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="img_container">
  <div class="boximgobj">
    <img src="http://minionslovebananas.com/images/gallery/preview/Chiquita-DM2-gallery_minion_cupcake.jpg?w=373&h=400" />
  </div>
</div>
```